# Is there a way to add accented characters support to the QRcode package?

Tags: packages, accents, french, spanish, german

Is there a way to add accented characters support to the qrcode package ?

```
    \documentclass[french]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[]{qrcode}
    \begin{document}

    \qrcode[]{ààààççççééééùùùùïïï}% produces an error: accented characters

    \qrcode[]{Are accented characters supported by the qrcode package ?}% works well

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you compile your document using a UTF-8 aware engine such as LuaTeX or XeTeX, the code works:

```
% Compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[]{qrcode}
\begin{document}

\qrcode[]{ààààççççééééùùùùïïï}% produces no error: accented characters

\bigskip
\qrcode[]{Are accented characters supported by the qrcode package ?}% works well

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Indeed, it works well with XeLatex. Is there another way, independent of XeLatex, to add full UTF-8 support to the QRcode package ?